# python replace pattern with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have this string.

```
a='SAD; Happy; ING:train coca'
OR
a='SAD; Happy; ING(train coca'
OR
a='SAD, Happy, ING[train coca'
```

I need to detect this string :   "; ING:"
for that I use this regex    :

```
listRE=re.findall(r';\s*[A-Z]+\s*[\:|\[|\(]\s*[A-Z]+', a)
```

What i need to do is to delete what is between ; and : (not always ; : as shown in the regex)

I do that

```
for i in listRE:
   p=re.compile(i)
   a=re.sub(p, r'', a)
```

but it s deleting my text !!
my target is :

```
a='SAD; Happy; train coca'
```

your help is more than welcome
Thank you for your help

Comment: Try `\s+\w+\s?[:([]\s*` https://regex101.com/r/Oj3w8o/1

Answer (score 1):

This does the job:

```
import re

strs = [
    'SAD; Happy; ING:train coca',
    'SAD; Happy; ING(train coca',
    'SAD, Happy, ING[train coca',
]
for str in strs:
    x = re.sub(r'(?<=[;,])\s+[A-Z]+[:([]', ' ', str)
    print x
```

**Output:**

```
SAD; Happy; train coca
SAD; Happy; train coca
SAD, Happy, train coca
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/UUDhWz/1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `findall` – you can use a regex pattern directly that matches all cases you need. I've also fixed up some of your regex:

```py
import re
a = 'SAD; Happy; ING:train coca'
b = "SAD; Happy; ING(train coca"
c = "SAD, Happy, ING[train coca"

print(re.sub(r'(?<=;|,)(\s*)[^:[(;,]*[:[(]', r'\1', a))
print(re.sub(r"(?<=;|,)(\s*)[^:[(;,]*[:[(]", r"\1", b))
print(re.sub(r"(?<=;|,)(\s*)[^:[(;,]*[:[(]", r"\1", c))

"""
output:
SAD; Happy; train coca
SAD; Happy; train coca
SAD, Happy, train coca
"""
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that s not exactly what i want.

Comment: @Gandalf could you clarify then?

Comment: yes I will explain : I have 3 cases  CASE 1  ;or, art1 : art2 art3  ==> ;or, art2 art3 \n CASE2  ;or, art1 ( art2 art3 ) ==> ;or, art2 art3   \n   CASE 3   ;or, art1 [ art2 art3 ] ==> ;or, art2 art3

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to match the strings from the comments, you might use

```
\s+\w+\s?[:([]\s*
```

In the replacement use a space.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oj3w8o/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wTd7In)

---

If you can match either a colon or from an opening till closing bracket afterwards, you might use an alternation matching either the `:` or use 2 capturing group where you would match the content to keep between the brackets `[...]` and `(...)`

```
\s+\w+\s?(?::|\(\s*([^()]+)\s*\)|\[\s*([^]\[]+)\s*])\s*
```

In the replacement use a space and both capturing groups `r' \1\2'`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Af5SYP/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pS4d8q)